# Merging a range of excel cells in a column into one single cell seperated by new lines

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, split

I need help with excel.

I have a column with hundreds of cells that I need to combine into one cell.

The values in the cells are already centered. Also, some cells have multiple values that are stacked on top of each other using (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

I need to choose a range of these cells and combine them and stack them on top of each other into one cell.

If I can also get rid of extra "new lines" between the values as well as repeated values that would be an added bonus.

Here is a picture of what it looks like and what I'm aiming at. I've been trying to learn vbscript and macros, but this is on a bit of a deadline. I appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: Vbscript is not vba. Please clarify what solution you want.  Also, please include your attempted code. SO is not a code writing device and you're more likely to get assistance if you demonstrate some effort first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows you how to combine all numbers from a column into a single cell in VBA Excel, which is what I assume the coding language you are using.

There are two Procedures I use: **1) a `columnCombine()` Sub** and **2) a Custom `Split()` Function** courtesy of Wade Tai of Microsoft

> Link to Wade's Article with Split Function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155763%28office.10%29.aspx

**`columnCombine()` Sub:**

```
Sub columnCombine()
    'variables needed:
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim endRow As Integer
    Dim firstCell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim destinationCell As Range
    Dim strg As Variant
    Dim strgTemp() As String

    'enter first and last cells of column of interest in the "A1/A2/A3..." format below:'
    Set firstCell = Range("A1") 'this can be what you want
    Set lastCell = Range("A3")  'this can be what you want

    'enter destination cell in same format as above
    Set destinationCell = Range("B1") 'this can be what you want

    'get column of interest
    col = firstCell.Column

    'get start row and end row
    startRow = firstCell.Row
    endRow = lastCell.Row

    'set temp string
    strg = ""

    For i = startRow To endRow
        strgTemp = Split(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, col).Value)
        For Each s In strgTemp
            If strg = "" Then
                strg = s
            Else
                strg = strg & vbNewLine & s
            End If
        Next s
        Erase strgTemp
    Next i
    'add column to string
    destinationCell.Value = strg

End Sub
```

**`Split()` Function:**

```
Public Function Split(ByVal InputText As String, _
         Optional ByVal Delimiter As String) As Variant

' This function splits the sentence in InputText into
' words and returns a string array of the words. Each
' element of the array contains one word.

    ' This constant contains punctuation and characters
    ' that should be filtered from the input string.
    Const CHARS = "!?,;:""'()[]{}"
    Dim strReplacedText As String
    Dim intIndex As Integer

    ' Replace tab characters with space characters.
    strReplacedText = Trim(Replace(InputText, _
         vbTab, " "))

    ' Filter all specified characters from the string.
    For intIndex = 1 To Len(CHARS)
        strReplacedText = Trim(Replace(strReplacedText, _
            Mid(CHARS, intIndex, 1), " "))
    Next intIndex

    ' Loop until all consecutive space characters are
    ' replaced by a single space character.
    Do While InStr(strReplacedText, "  ")
        strReplacedText = Replace(strReplacedText, _
            "  ", " ")
    Loop

    ' Split the sentence into an array of words and return
    ' the array. If a delimiter is specified, use it.
    'MsgBox "String:" & strReplacedText
    If Len(Delimiter) = 0 Then
        Split = VBA.Split(strReplacedText)
    Else
        Split = VBA.Split(strReplacedText, Delimiter)
    End If
End Function
```

***UPDATE:**

If you desire to use this on multiple different columns with the intention of moving everything to one cell, use this code recursively or in some repetitive manner e.g. write a script that uses columnCombine to combine the column sections you are referencing into different cells in one column. Then run the program again (or as many times as you need) so that you get the data into one cell.

If you want to change the order in which you iterate through a column e.g. you want to iterate from A4 to A1 instead of A1 to A4, just change `For i = startRow To endRow` to `For i = endRow To startRow`. 
*Note this will not change the order of organization of data within an individual cell, only a whole column. In other words, `{["hello","Hello"],["One"],["Two", "Three"]}` would become `{["Two","Three"],["One"],["hello","Hello"]}`*

To change the order within a cell, you would need to either alter the `For Each` statement in `columnCombine()` or 
manually change the order of `strg`. Both of which are not to hard to do.

Here is a solution I would do:

Add this in addition to the current variables :

```
Dim strg2 As Variant 
strg2 = ""
```

Change this code:

```
For i = startRow To endRow
    strgTemp = Split(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, col).Value)
    For Each s In strgTemp
        If strg = "" Then
            strg = s
        Else
            strg = strg & vbNewLine & s
        End If
    Next s
    Erase strgTemp
Next i
'add column to string
destinationCell.Value = strg
```

To:

```
For i = endRow To startRow
    strgTemp = Split(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, col).Value)
    For Each s In strgTemp
        If strg = "" Then
            strg = s
        Else
            strg = s & vbNewLine & strg
        End If
    Next s
    If strg2 = "" Then
        strg2 = strg
    Else
        strg2 = strg2 & vbNewLine & strg
    End If
    strg = ""
    Erase strgTemp
Next i
'add column to string
destinationCell.Value = strg2
```

*Remember, this change is specific to iterating through items backward and reordering them backwards. The `columnCombine()` sub will very depending on how you want the data presented*

[image: profile for CSAW at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Comment: This is probably not the most efficient way to do it, but it seems to me like you don't care too much about that.

Comment: I appreciate the help. If there is a more efficient way, I would most definitely appreciate it. I just need this done by the end of the week. I'm not sure if VBA uses global variable or something, but essentially I have a column of close to 500 cells. The function that the above executes is correct, but I need to do this for different ranges at the same time if possible. So for instance run the function for A1 - A6 place in B1. Do the same for A7 to A1 place in B2. So on and so forth. If that's possible that would be awesome. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I could run the macro over and over again no problem. Is there any way to clean it up. For instance I want them delimited by "new lines". So each is stacked on top of each other. The column i'm working with might have some wasted line space. So when I combine it, it might be (this is read from top to bottom)  S1.2.0 "blank line" "blank line" S.2.0 "blank line" S.3.0S.4.0S.5.0 "blank line" S.6.0 so on so forth. If there is anyway I can removed the wasted blank line space within one call I have all the values stacked on top of each other neatly, would be ideal.

Comment: Great explanation. Is there some sort of input reader within VBA? For instance, I want use the function rapidly with some hot keys. Instead of manually entering in the range, is there a way to highlight the range and execute a hot key? Thanks for you help again.

Comment: To answer you question about the hot key, you can set any macro to a hot key. In excel Developer>Macros>Options will lead you to the hot key menu. Regarding the second question, there are many ways to get the reference for a selected cell. `ActiveCell` will give you the range of the cell you last pressed. Since there are multiple cells of interest, you might want to make a User Form to direct your selection of cells so you assign the correct cells to the correct values. The simplest solution is probably placing some `MsgBox`s in `columnCombine()` telling you when to select the relevant cell.

Comment: Also, if you are satisfied with an Answer, mark it as the solution so others know your problem is solved.

Comment: thank you for your help! This answered my question and gave me a nice understanding of VBA.